# I can't log into Salesforce help to contact Customer Support

Tags: salesforce-support

I've been having issues with my developer console, such as the theme always resetting no matter how many times I change it, the scroll bar jumping, and most recently, this error:

> An unexpected error has occurred. 1462354483-17177 (-873769799) for deploymentId=1dr6F000003RAORQA4 If this persists, please contact customer support.

That prevents me from saving any darn file on dev console. So I wanted to contact customer support at https://help.salesforce.com/home, but when I try logging in with my org, it always auto-logs me out.

Also, I have cookies enabled and I'm using Chrome. What do I do to contact support?

Comment: If this is a DE account there is no support and unless  you have another paid org you are basically SOL

Comment: @Eric. Yes, it is a dev org. Also, what is SOL?

Comment: From urban dictionary: SOL -Acronym for the words of "Shit Out of Luck." It is used in reference to the state of having run out of all other options, wherein the remaining situation is less than desirable.

Comment: @Kasper Haha :-) Thought it had something to do with salesforce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't figured out how to contact customer support, but for reference, if anyone wants to know how I got rid of the unexpected error, then this is for you.

Since saving is no longer possible on the dev console, you'll have to close dev console, go access your vf page through Setup > Pages, and then edit the page and save it.

Then reopen dev console and the error should have gone.